# Boostrap 4 Toast not showing after calling it

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Boostrap 4 website, and I need to implement Toast on UI.

This is my boilerplate template:

```
<!-- Toast -->
<div class="toast" id="myToast">
    <div class="toast-header">
        <strong class="mr-auto"><i class="fa fa-grav"></i> We miss you!</strong>
        <small>11 mins ago</small>
        <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
        It's been a long time since you visited us. We've something special for you. <a href="#">Click here!</a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Images LazyLoad -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/5.1.0/lazysizes.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Twitter Bootstrap & Behaviors Like Tooltips etc -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Responsive Navigation Menu -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SlickNav/1.0.10/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("Call Toast");
        $("#myToast").toast('show');
    });
</script>
```

The website loads perfectly, but the notification Toast never display, Is there a way to diagnose or debug?

In console I got 0 errors and warnings.

It just show broken at top of the page, even before navbar.

[image: Toast showed at top left]

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle or a runable script?

Comment: and you do have bootstrap css loaded in?

Comment: Yes I have <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: If you just copied and pasted that then there is your problem right there... left off the https:// from the start of the path

Comment: Well, i now works, but show as a solid div at beggining of the web. How to make it look as a floating notification bottom-left

updating preview...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue number 1 that was resolved in my comment regarding correction of your css path.

Additional request regarding positioning:

Per documentation, the recommended way to control position is to apply inline styles to the toast element. For bottom, left (per request) would be controlled in such manner:

```
<div class="toast" id="myToast" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;">
 <div class="toast-header">
     <strong class="mr-auto"><i class="fa fa-grav"></i> We miss you!</strong>
     <small>11 mins ago</small>
     <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast">&times;</button>
 </div>
 <div class="toast-body">
     It's been a long time since you visited us. We've something special for you. <a href="#">Click here!</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Another piece of information that has helped usability for me personally has been to modify the duration of which the notification is displayed as I believe that the default show period is way to short for users to even see. To do this you will want to at the following data attribute to your element:  data-delay="milisecond value"

Attached is a full example:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myToast").toast('show');
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<!-- Toast -->
<div class="toast" id="myToast" data-delay="3000"  style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 10px;">
    <div class="toast-header">
        <strong class="mr-auto"><i class="fa fa-grav"></i> We miss you!</strong>
        <small>11 mins ago</small>
        <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
        It's been a long time since you visited us. We've something special for you. <a href="#">Click here!</a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Images LazyLoad -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/5.1.0/lazysizes.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Twitter Bootstrap & Behaviors Like Tooltips etc -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Responsive Navigation Menu -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SlickNav/1.0.10/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
```